# PropertyAccessException when using memcache with property lazy loading

Tags: nhibernate, memcached, lazy-loading

I'm working on a project that uses NHibernate (v 3.3.0.4000) and memcache (v 3.1.0.4000 which is the latest available).

I have a large field containing pretty big strings. As I do not want to load this field with every call, I've configured the property as "lazy loading" with Fluent Nhibernate .

Everything works fine (my property is loaded on demand) except when memcache is enabled. Iget this exception :

```
NHibernate.PropertyAccessException: The type System.Object can not be assigned to a property of type System.String setter of XYZ ---> System.ArgumentException: Impossible de convertir l'objet de type 'System.Object' en type 'System.String'.
```

I guess the problem is related to the version of "NHibernate.Caches.MemCache", which is quite old and doesn't seem to be alive.

I would like to know if anyone has managed to run memcache with lazy properties . If not, is it possible to disable cache for a single property ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this was a known bug: 
[Retrieving object from 2nd cache with lazy property fails](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2898)

And, fortunately for you, it was fixed in the latest release (3.3.2, as of today)

Just update NHibernate and the problem will be gone.

Comment: Thank you Diego! Your hint definitely helped me ! And it works now like a charm.